# Embed youtube in UIWebview

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, youtube

everyone , I'm try to embed youtube movie in app

I find it need to use HTML link ,I search some reference

[Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html)

[Youtube API Blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html)

But I don't about HTML , I have no idea about HTML

I follow the instruction write these code

```
NSString *video_ID = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/ng7fl_fKCRQ";

NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",video_ID];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Is that right ???

Or I need to add  ,  ... or something in my htmlStr ???

/*Edit*/

After fix the video id , It can run on the simulator , Why my webview size is the same as UIView but still has a blank edge ???

It looks like this pic

[image]

Thanks for any reply or answer

Best regards :)

Webber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add some finish touches remove everything from video_ID variable except the actual video ID, so video_ID will contain @"ng7fl_fKCRQ" - it should load nicely.